# Getting error in building project of watchkit watchos2 app

Tags: swift, watchkit

error: /Users/shinetechnolab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Argo-agpfpuxrfutxsnasocfqftbcutqf/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/ArgoWatchApp.app: No such file or directory

I don't know what's went wrong with this before changing the bundle identifier it was working fine as soon as I have changed the bundle id I have got this error.

I have got this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15202 link too in searching of my answer that might be helpful for you to provide me my solution.

If any one knows why then please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you change the bundle identifier? The watch extension has a reference to the watch app's bundle identifier, so they need to match up if you changed it.

Comment: Thank you for reply !
I have solved this issue early, I know that watch extension refers to the watch app's bundle identifier, but the problem was $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) not working when I hard coded gave current new bundle identifier in info.plist of watch app then that worked for me.